# The method loadTree(InputStream) from the type SaveService is deprecatedJava(67108967) JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, jmx

I'm trying to run JMeter script using JMeter 3.1, where the SaveService.loadTree() function is depricated. Would anyone be so kind and suggest what should I do, when the scripts I need to process are written in JMeter 3.1.
This is the error message:
'The method loadTree(InputStream) from the type SaveService is deprecatedJava(67108967)'
Thanks in advance! :)
I'd like to create an automated solution of running JMeter scripts and testing different variations of changes. If you know any resource that might help me or others interested in the topic, please share, we'll be most grateful to you!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the function is [deprecated](https://www.baeldung.com/java-deprecated) doesn't mean it cannot be used, it's just a warning that it might be removed in one of the next releases, as long as it does what you expect it's absolutely fine to use it.

If you need to get rid of this compile-time warning: looking into the latest [JavaDoc for SaveService](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/save/SaveService.html#loadTree-java.io.File-) it now takes [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) as the parameter so you should do something like:

```
HashTree testPlan = SaveService.loadTree(new File("/path/to/your/script.jmx"));
```

You might also be interested in [JMeter DSL](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterdsl-performance-testing-developers/) as "pure" [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) is not too friendly and readable.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any experience with autonomous JMeter scripts testing?